# How Many Hundreds Fit Into the Number?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.

I want to know how many hundreds fit into each number. So 894 would equal 8. 323 would equal 3.

This is the code which I've written, and as you can guess it's not working.

```js
function howManyHundreds(num) {
  return num / 100;
  return num % 10;
}

console.log(howManyHundreds(894))

console.log(howManyHundreds(323))
```

894 would be printed to 8.94 and 323 would be 3.23

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to know? Am I using the modulus operator wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your function has two return statements.

Comment: I ran that. It was incorrect. num % 100 I mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `Math.floor` to get the integer component of the division. You can see the updated code in snippet below:

```js
function howManyHundreds (num) {
  var division = num / 100;
  return Math.floor(division);
}

console.log(howManyHundreds(894));
console.log(howManyHundreds(323));
```

Note: Keep in mind that this wouldn't work as you expect with negative numbers. If you need that you can use `Math.abs` to get the absolute value and then get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the integer value after division.

```js
function howManyHundreds(num) {
  return Math.floor(num / 100);
}

console.log(howManyHundreds(894))

console.log(howManyHundreds(323))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just floor the division result:

```js
function howManyHundreds(num) {
  return Math.floor(num / 100);
}

console.log(howManyHundreds(894))
console.log(howManyHundreds(323))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Math.floor()` method for get numeric value